# jenkins pipeline using java.io.file always references the master

Tags: java, file, jenkins, shared-libraries

I have a Jenkins pipeline;

```
@Library('sharedLib@master') 
import org.foo.point

pipeline {
    agent { label 'slaveone' }
//  agent { label 'master' }
    stages {
        stage('Data Build'){
            steps{
                script{
                    def Point = new point()
                    Point.hello("mememe")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which runs a small bit of code in a library called 'jenkins-shared-library/src/sharedLib';

```
package org.foo

import java.io.File
class point{
    def hello(name){
        File saveFile = new File("c:/temp/jenkins_log.txt")
        saveFile.write "hello"
    }
}
```

It runs fine on both 'master' and 'slaveone', but in both cases the 'jenkins_log.txt' file appears on the master. The log file contains this;

`Running on slaveone in d:\Jenkins_WorkDir\workspace\mypipeline`

How is this code running on slaveone and writing files to master?

Edit: I should also mention that this is my third attempt at doing this. The first one was with Groovy code direct in the pipeline, and the second was using a 'def' type call in the vars directory. Both produced the same behaviour, seemingly oblivious to the agent it was being run on.

Comment: It could help if you'd explain why is it needed to create the file on the slave. If there are two stages, one that creates a file and another one that reads it, my expectation is that the read succeeds regardless of the nodes running these stages.

Comment: Our company policy is that no job should run on master, all pipelines should only run on slaves (in most cases these will be Docker Containers only spun up for the duration of the pipeline). While there is a 'write' and 'read' process, both are happening on master. I produced this example as minimum viable code.

Comment: You can then try `sh "echo hello > jenkins_log.txt"`, this will run on slave.

Comment: Thanks MaratC, your comment reminded me of something I tried earlier in the process but dismissed. Groovy's own 'writefile' and 'readfile' seem to work fine. I'm not sure why I moved to java.io.file (and I'm sure I'll remember extremely soon!), but for now I can stay with the Groovy commands to do the same job. Thanks again.

Comment: Now I remember why I moved to java.io.file. The step prior to this is to get a list of all files in a directory. I have various options for getting a list of files,  but they all seem to have the same issue, IE work on master but fail on slave.

Comment: Try `def list_of_all_files = sh script: "ls -la", returnOutput:true`, this too will run on slave.

Comment: Yep, that looks like the solution for file lists, although I had to vary it slightly as I'm currently using a Windows slave; `= bat(script: "dir /b /a-d <folder>",returnStdout: true, label: 'mycommand')`

Answer (score 1):

I think everything inside the script runs on master, but here I found a workaround:  [Jenkins Declarative Pipeline, run groovy script on slave agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748826/jenkins-declarative-pipeline-run-groovy-script-on-slave-agent)

Comment: Yes, I think that's the only option at the moment, run a series of 'sh' or 'bat' commands similar to what was mentioned above. It makes the script look pretty ugly though...

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins stores all logs on master only, that's why you cannot find any log on nodes.

Comment: This is nothing to do with logs. These are files being generated by the pipeline.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748826/jenkins-declarative-pipeline-run-groovy-script-on-slave-agent